Maui FlexLayout takes a lot of height
I'm Trying to add items that they align in a row, but when they reach the max width they wrap in another row.
I've doing this with a FlexLayout and the propierty "Wrap", that's fine, but i realized that the height of the FlexLayout its greater than i wanted it to be. That is because I've got a ScrollView and it activates when i only have a few items in the FlexLayout. Changing the Backgroud color of the FlexLayout and adding items one by one, I realized that the height its almost the size of the items x number of items, even if they are all in a row, the height stills to increase.
If i remove the "Wrap" the over height disapears, but i want that feature.
I thank you in advance .
Here some examples:
The Yellow is the FlexLayout Background
With one item it works fine
With Many Items the Yellow zone is bigger and the Scroll activates
In Summary I'm looking for a way to make the FlexLayout height adapt to the children's height.
Here is the code:
Main Xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local = "clr-namespace:Vista.Controls.Views"
    x:Class="Vista.MainPage" >

    <ScrollView Orientation="Both">
        <VerticalStackLayout 
            BackgroundColor="Red"
        >
            <FlexLayout x:Name="FlexLayoutControl"
                Wrap="Wrap"
                Direction="Row"
                AlignItems="Start"
                JustifyContent="Start"
                AlignContent="Start"
                BackgroundColor="Yellow"
            
            />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>

ContentView (Blocks that goes in the FlexLayout)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="Vista.Controls.Views.FileView">

    <Border Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"
        Padding="10"
        MaximumHeightRequest="100"
        MaximumWidthRequest="200"
        HeightRequest="100"
        WidthRequest="100"
        BackgroundColor="#FF00FF"
    >
        <VerticalStackLayout 
            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            >
            <Label x:Name="textoLabel"
                Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Border>
</ContentView>


In C# i dont have much, only controls to add the FileView to the FlexLayout. I'll put it up anyway in case you need it.
MainPage C#:

using Vista.Controls.Views;

namespace Vista
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _reload();
        }

        private void ToolBarItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String opcion = "vacío";

            try
            {
                opcion = (sender as ToolbarItem)?.Text ?? "No era ToolbarItem";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                opcion = $"Excepcion {ex.Message}";
            }

            switch (opcion)
            {
                case "Añadir":
                    _addOpcion();
                    break;
                case "Modificar":
                    _reload();
                    break;
                case "Eliminar":
                    _limpiar();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void _addOpcion()
        {
            mainVerticalLayout.Add(
                new FileView()
            );
        }

        private void _reload()
        {
            _limpiar();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                mainVerticalLayout.Add(
                    new FileView($"Prueba text {i + 1}")
                );
            }
        }

        private void _limpiar()
        {
            mainVerticalLayout.Clear();
        }
    }
}


FileView C#:
namespace Vista.Controls.Views;

public partial class FileView : ContentView
{
    public FileView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public FileView(String texto)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textoLabel.Text = texto;
    }
}

FlexLayout Wrapping is taking a lot of height when add items to it. I want it to be the same as the children.

You can fix this by changing the Orientation of the ScrollView to Vertical. My code works fine.

I can't believe this actually worked. Thank you so much.

Here is My solution.
Change the Orientation of the ScrollView to Vertical.
<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">


